# Django REST framework - serializer.object.value='x' before serializer.save() doesn't change value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple POST right now doing the following -

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = CalendarSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.object.evntmst_name='cal_test'
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I have an XML that I'm importing on post where the evntmst_name is "cal_daily".  On doing a post it successfully goes through but the value for evntmst_name is not changing.  After post I get the same value of "cal_daily" in the database instead of "cal_test" which it should be set to.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out by doing it another way, or the way I wanted to do it (in the view) is not possible.  I've made 2 separate serializers 1 for GET and 1 for PUT/PATCH.

In the serializer for PUT/PATCH I've defined the logic to change the field value like so -

```
class CalendarPUTSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Evntmst
        resource_name = 'evntmst'
        fields = ('evntmst_id', 'evntmst_name')

    def transform_evntmst_id(self, obj, value):
        if obj.evntmst_id == 1939:
            return 1937
```